# PHP not showing all errors despite E_ALL being set

Tags: php, wampserver

In my php.ini file I have the following line set:

`error_reporting = E_ALL`

`display_errors` is also turned on in the ini file.

However, this does not appear to be working correctly because I can only get PHP to display strict errors when I add the following to my PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

I'm using Wampserver, why is this happening? I want PHP to display all errors no matter what the severity without having to include this code in every file.

Comment: And you did restart your Wampserver?

Comment: Maybe you are only making STRICT errors

Comment: I am only making strict errors. I thought as of 5.4 E_ALL includes strict errors?

Comment: It does. Now which `php.ini` file are you editing, there are 2. Also which version of WAMPServer are you using. Also which version of PHP are you using

Comment: I've checked the `php.ini` file in the `bin/php/(version)` folder for each version. Is there another file this would be in? Using Wampserver 3.0.6.

Comment: By default WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG configured and turned on. Do you not get Orange Errors message on your browser?

Comment: exactly, which file are you editing? The one you need is in *C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache_version\bin*, or wherever you installed wamp

Comment: `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\php.ini` is a `.symlink` and I can't edit it....

Comment: @kjdion84 You should always use the menu system to get to the correct `php.ini` file for the current Apache/PHP environment

Comment: I do. That is where I see E_ALL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAMPServer, has 2 `php.ini` files

In the `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\`  folder. This controls ONLY PHP CLI.

If you want to effect the Apache web server environment you should always use the menus to get to the correct file, as it changes as you change Apache/PHP versions

So

```
left click wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

and this will edit the correct file for the current Apache/PHP activated.

But by default error reporting and XDEBUG should be turned on

Comment: XDEBUG is turned on and it is showing non-strict errors. I am trying to get it to show errors such as when undeclared variables are used. I have `error_reporting = E_ALL` in the PHP file you mentioned when I click the wamp manager and go to `PHP->php.ini`. Do I need to add E_STRICT? Like I said I thought this was included in 5.4.

Comment: Are you running code you have written, or are you fixing someone elses code that you are not familiar with

Comment: I'm running code I have written and I don't want there to be any errors because sometimes a non-strict error occurs which breaks the page and I have absolutely no idea why until I manually add the code I mentioned in OP.

Comment: I think maybe the problem is that I need to enable non-strict error reporting? Sorry for being so confusing it's been a long night.

Comment: Just a possibility! I dont suppose you have turned any error reporting off in your INIT functionality?